# How do I use the IANA Timezone database?

Tags: database

http://www.iana.org/time-zones

I want to query this.  I really, really do... I'm using PHP and I'm starting to try and make relational things out of the Timezone data with arrays... I'd really like to just query it but I have no idea how to open it.  (lol?)

Or the database listed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php  (PECL)

This is not for production use.  It is for my own sanity.  I'm gonna keep going with my array thing... but...

I just really want to know if each city is an individual timezone with individual rules.  I do not care about the past - only current.  At first I assumed that no, of course not, some of those share timezones and they were just nice and listed more than one city per zone.  But!  DST rules might be different.  Who knows.

How do I open this thing?

Comment: Lots of info [here](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html), especially the "other tz binary readers" section.  Unfortunately none in php it seems, but the code presented there should help you to understand how to read the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has the timezone database built in, just use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) classes.

Example:

```
$utc_date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
                'Y-m-d G:i', 
                '2011-04-27 02:45', 
                new DateTimeZone('UTC')
);

$nyc_date = $utc_date;
$nyc_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

echo $nyc_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A'); // output: 2011-04-26 10:45 PM
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806875)